# Как убрать вложенность в python?

Tags: python

```
arr = [[1], [2], ['asfasf']]

>>> arr
[1, 2, 'asfasf']
```

Comment: нашел, sum(x, [])

Comment: Тут еще варианты решения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271146/how-to-remove-the-innermost-level-of-nesting-in-a-list-of-lists-of-varying-lengt

Comment: вы бы поискали ответ на этот сайте на свой вопрос - его задают чуть ли не каждый месяц ленивые люди. и ответ, который вы нашли - самый НЕ рекомендуемый к использованию.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать методом extend добавить в пустую строку)
это если по простому)

```
x = []
arr = [[1], [2], ['asfasf']]
for i in arr:
    x.extend(i)
print(x)
```